# Clarification on okhttp dispatcher thread pool max threads

Tags: okhttp

what is the max thread count for
1)dispatcher thread pool
2)MaxRequestsPerHost (dispatcher)
3)MaxRequests (dispatcher)

Answer (score 0):

1. is builtin. No need to take care yourself.
2. 5 concurrent requests per host.
3. 64 concurrent requests.